# Learn parameters for truncated Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, skewness, gaussian-mixture-distribution, skew-normal-distribution

I would like to learn the parameters for a truncated gaussian like this one.
[image]

I'm using this formula for the probability density
$f(x | \mu, \sigma^2) = \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \times \frac{1}{F(\mu, \sigma)}\times \mathbb{1}_{x>0}$

where $F(\mu, \sigma)$ is a function so that the integral of $f$ over $x$ equals $1$.

I tried to derive the maximum likelihood like we usually do for gaussian mixtures, but then I got stuck : I can't find an easy formula for $\mu$ and $\sigma$. How to find them?

Comment: This histogram isn't Gaussian in appearance, truncated or not: its right tail is much too heavy. So: would you like answers to the question you asked or would you like advice about how to characterize the data you show?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to characterize the data. But I would be glad to hear an answer for the first question as well :)

Comment: what kind of data is this ?

Comment: It is a histogram for a molecule concentration

Comment: taken over time or space ? or does it represent cross-sectional data

Comment: A truncated distribution would not ordinarily be a good choice to model a concentration.  Consider a lognormal or possibly a Gamma distribution instead.

Comment: over time & space.

Comment: thank you ! I'll try what you suggested to me. Why would a truncated distribution be a bad choice?

Comment: So do you have correlated observations on one sample taken at fixed intervals over time ? If so how many individual samples do you have and how many observations are made on each sample ,, and then what is your total # of readings/measurements ?

Comment: I have measurements of a molecule concentration at differents places at fixed intervals over time. I have ~ 100.000 observations.

Comment: Perhaps what you have is a composite picture and you should be looking at separate pictures/histograms .

Answer (score 2):

To be clear about what you written in your probability density function, this is a form of *truncation*. In other words, if $X < 0$, then $X$ does not appear in the data set. As such, it will *not* be described as a Gaussian Mixture Model.

When treating this as a maximum likelihood problem, there are no constraints on $\mu$ or $\log(\sigma)$. So vanilla optimization algorithms, like Newton Raphsons, should be able to optimize the likelihood without much problem.

Alternatively, if you really wanted to fit an EM algorithm, I believe you could do this by having the dropped $X$'s be your missing data. However, this will be a little tricky; your missing data will not just be values of unobserved $X$, but *how many* $X$*'s are missing*. The formula for the expected of number missing $X$'s would be $\frac{n}{1 - \Phi(-\mu / \sigma)} - n$. This will not be a whole number with probability 1!

You should still be able to get a closed form M step by using a weight sample, but this is starting to get considerably more complicated than just using Newton Raphson's at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I am going to try a Newton Raphsons then.